# Running a Java applet on a website

Tags: java, html, eclipse, applet

I have created a Java game using Eclipse.  It has 11 classes (with one main class that calls everything else).  I called it as an applet in the following manner:

```
<!-- This is the applet handler to load the Handler Class to run the game -->
<td colspan="3"><applet code="Handler.class" codebase="History Adventure Alamo Adventure/" name="Alamo Battle Adventure" width="680" height="509" archive="Handler.jar" id="Alamo Battle Adventure">
</applet></td>
```

With it uploaded to the website, it shows an error and tells me to click for details.  When I select it, it tells me ClassNotFoundException:  Handler.class

The code is in the body and I have nothing in the head.  What have I done wrong?

Here is the rest of my code for the page.  The actual test page can be found at www.kluckhohndesign.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=510,width=500');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>

<title>Alamo Battle Adventure</title>
</head>

<body>
<blockquote>&nbsp;</blockquote>
<table width="1300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="318" height="160">&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3"><img src="Alamo Battle Adventure.jpg" width="680" height="160" alt="Top Banner" /></td>
    <td width="318">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="226"><a href="howtoplay.html" onclick="return popitup('howtoplay.html')"><img src="How to Play.jpg" width="226" height="52" alt="How to Play" /></a></td>
    <td width="226">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="227"><a href="Help.html" onclick="return popitup('help.html')"><img src="help.jpg" width="226" height="52" alt="Help" /></a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="Alamo Pencil.jpg" width="318" height="250" alt="Alamo Drawing" /></td>
<!-- This is the applet handler to load the Handler Class to run the game -->
    <td colspan="3"><applet code="Handler.jar" codebase="History Adventure Alamo Adventure/" name="Alamo Battle Adventure" width="680" height="509" archive="Handler.jar" id="Alamo Battle Adventure" />
    </applet></td>
    <td><img src="texans.jpg" width="318" height="250" alt="Texans Drawing" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `archive` parameter specifies the relative path to your JAR file. Is `Handler.jar` in the same directory as this web page?

Comment: Does your class live inside a package? So should the value of code be "your.package.Handler.class" Also the codebase should be a URL. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html

Comment: My handler.jar file is in the same directory as the .class file which is in the same directory as the webpage.  The Java class files were all created with Eclipse.  Do I need to package them all together so that I only have one package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you further:

```html
<html>
<body>
<applet
    code="Handler"
    codebase="http://www.kluckhohndesign.com/History%20Adventure%20Alamo%20Adventure/"
    name="Alamo Battle Adventure"
    width="680"
    height="509"
    archive="Handler.jar"
    id="Alamo Battle Adventure" >
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

You can leave out the `http://www.kluckhohndesign.com/` prefix on the codebase.

Now it causes an `InvocationTargetException`.  But ask a new question about that.

### Further notes

1. The `code` attribute should be the fully qualified name of the **class** & has nothing to do with the Jar.  Most people think FQN equates to `Handler.class` but it actually means just `Handler`.
2. The codebase can be simply `History%20Adventure%20Alamo%20Adventure/` if it is coming off your site.  It needs the `%20` for spaces, as spaces are not valid in an URL.  Then again, most deployers would not use directory names with spaces at all, for that very reason.
3. The `applet` element was never meant to be 'self closed' as was shown in your original page.  Instead it needs an explicit `</applet>` closing element.
4. Please keep testing in the simpler page I suggested, without all that other cruft.

Comment: That's definitely gotten me one step further than I was.