# Android Game Development Engine needed?

Tags: java, android, game-engine

I am new to Android / Android Game Development. I wrote a few basic Apps in Android Studio and want to make an 2D game like Flappybird/Crossyroad/Jetpack Joyride.

What exactly do I have to do for this (download,install,learn)?

Do I need an Engine, what exactly is an Engine, so dont I need Android Studio anymore.

Do I have to programm in Java? (I heared that an Engine can be in C# but how can this works fine on android[which is Java based? ])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm currently in the research and design phase for the development of a game right now so take this information out with a grain (or pinch) of salt:

A game engine is a what takes your game's data and "talks" to the hardware. Most game engines are written in C/C++. How this relates to Java game development is that when you write code in Java, and use Javac to compile your code, javac outputs that compilation to java-byte code, this in turn is read by a JVM. That in, mind the JVM is written in C. So what's happening is effectively a *hand wave* double engine, speed and efficiency are sometimes sacrificed for readability and ease of use.

Your Java based game engine is being run inside of a JVM with is effectively a Java engine running in C.

Essentially by using a Java based engine you're adding another layer of communication between your game and the hardware, which can affect performance.

A game engine can keep any customizable modules of your code from needing recompilation by utilizing a scripting language (like Lua or C#).

Using an engine for your game is best practice & industry standard.

There are a number of engines out there for you to use: [Wiki Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines)

You should pick one that works best for your development environment and project lifecycle. That being said, I'm really looking forward to giving [defold](http://www.defold.com/) a shot. It is 2D first, with the capability of publishing to most major platforms and being free, puts it right in line with my current project.

I hope this helps!

Comment: sorry but i dont get how an engine like LibGDX can be for more platforms. So you write your code in Java and than it can be runned as html, how is this possible?

Comment: Well, what is likely happening is that your java code is being compiled into an applet, and that applet is being thrown into a simple HTML template and that template hosts the applet for a user. For a more in depth explanation or rather another example of this see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283437/running-a-java-applet-on-a-website

Comment: ok but for me I will write in java for android so it isnt been compiled?

Comment: It will be compiled, if a program is running on a computer it is very likely compiled at some point in time.

Comment: If you make your game using LibGDX or some other multi-platform publishing development tool/environment, you will likely either select the target environment (android/iOS/windows/mac) at time of project or when you are ready to publish your project you can select the target environment at that time.

Comment: "at time of project or when " == at the time of project creation

Answer (score 1):

LibGDX - Desktop/Android/BlackBerry/iOS/HTML5 Java game development framework.  [Link](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)

Comment: to you have to code in java?

Comment: You can work with Android Studio. Full Java language support and you will find tutorials and examples how step by step setup

Comment: can you programm an enginge in multiple languages or what?

Comment: With this framework you write logic on Java and can build for other platform OS.

Comment: is it good/fast for android

Comment: how to use it right, need to download it (an .exe for windows). Or are it just files which you import in your androis studio project?

Comment: Are you watch step by step tutorial setup?